# Click and drag the CGContext drawing to position it anywhere on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(MyImage.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        tempImage.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: MyImage.frame.size.width, height: MyImage.frame.size.height))
        context?.move(to: startPoint)
        context?.addLine(to: point)
        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(3)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        context?.setBlendMode(.normal)
        context?.strokePath()

        tempImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        tempImage.alpha = 1.0
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I am using the above code to draw freehand drawing over an image . After drawing the image is it possible to click anywhere on the drawing and move it to place it anywhere on the screen .

Comment: what you are trying to do could be achieved by using a transparent ***custom*** **UIView** above your image. you draw your lines over the transparent view, drag it anywhere. but you said anywhere on screen. what is the purpose of a drawing line over your screen?

Comment: @ImrulKayes Its not just a line , i am trying to add signature over an image.

Comment: Is there anyway i can add signature to my image like adding signature from built in markup on iphone

Comment: of course you can. I told you so in my previous comment. And I know what is a drawable line would be, but you mentioned screen rather your image. you just need a custom uiview.

Comment: check [this library](https://github.com/alankarmisra/SwiftSignatureView). from this library you can export your signature as a uiview/image. make that view movable and add over your image as a signature. research about this type of custom views. you might find a way.

Comment: @ImrulKayes I know how to get the image after drawing, my problem is , user must be able to drag the image  , and also user should me able to enlarge and shrik the image

Comment: you need to make custom UIView for that particular purpose. you can check [Library](https://github.com/luiyezheng/JLStickerTextView). read throughly the functionalities of this library.

Comment: I got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library: https://github.com/luiyezheng/JLStickerTextView
I think this what I what you are looking for.